# How to send a parameter to service method of c# user control?

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms, user-controls, webmethod

I am using following code in my HTML.

```
<uc1:BaseIntelliSenseControl ID="SmartPhrasesIntellisence" runat="server" 
                        ContextKey="0" ServiceMethod="GetSmartPhrases_Intellisence" ServicePath="~/patient/clinical/case/soap/smartphrases/lstSmartPhrases.aspx" 
                        Width="100%" OnClientItemSelected="selected_Item"  OnClientPopulated="clientPopulated" hint="Search Smart Phrases ..." />
```

I want to send a parameter which I have set in jquery ready function like this

```
$("#hdnCurrentlySelectedCategory").val($(this).val());
```

Service method is as follows

```
[WebMethod(EnableSession = true)]
public static string[] GetSmartPhrases_Intellisence(string prefixText, int count, string contextKey)
{

}
```

Is there any way I can pass another parameter or send set Context Key through jquery/javascript method?

I tried to do the following in jquery ready function

```
        var listObject = $find('autocompleteEx1');
        listObject.set_contextKey("Value");
```

But it did not work. Any help will be most appreciated.

Comment: can you add more code for clarification (user control), if you can pass 1 param then you can pass as many parameters as you want

Comment: @MukeshChudasama! Can we set context key through jquery/javascript as I can access Context key in service method?

Comment: you can pass as query string or post parameter which you can get in arguments.

Comment: How would it be possible? In a querystring, I am still unable to put parameter that would be set through javascript/jquery.

Comment: can you provide me javascript code which call this web method or usercontrol code so i can provide specific details

Comment: @MukeshChudasama I have updated my question.

Comment: still some javascript missing, i think javascript library is included in usercontrol or somewhere. e.g. ControlSearchClicked is defined in that js library

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have just discovered the solution to my problem. Here is the following code I did to update context key through jquery.

```
        var listObject = $find('<%=SmartPhrasesIntellisence.ControlID %>');
        listObject.set_contextKey("Value");
```

Here "SmartPhrasesIntellisence" is the id of user control that I set. It first finds it and use set_contextKey method. Previously I was using wrong id due to which I was facing problems.

Happy Coding!